# Getting variables values from Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

After a module is built, and checkpoint is stored in model_ckpt,
how can I get the values(weights, biases) of each node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to load a checkpoint then call

```
node_value = session.run(variable_name_here)
```

Where variable_name_here should be there weight tensor